# average of last x cells for dates < today()

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

We are tracking our orders in a google sheet. This sheet shows also the forecast of the products. Now we would like to get the average number of orders of the last 15 days. So the function must be sth like this:
=average(last 15 cells for dates before today)

[image]

I got this but its only working, if the forecast wouldnt be there:

```
=AVERAGE(INDEX(L3:ACV3;COUNTA(L3:ACV3)-14):ACV3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,

```
=average(index(3:3, 1, match(today(), 2:2, 0)-14):index(3:3, 1, match(today(), 2:2, 0)))
=average(index(3:3; 1; match(today(); 2:2; 0)-14):index(3:3; 1; match(today(); 2:2; 0)))
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but unfortunately I get the error message.. do I have to adjust this with my cells somehow? 
Could you maybe explain pls, what this is exactly doing?

Comment: No error message here; jjust the correct result. It locates today in row 2 and then averages row 3 from today to 14 columns previous (total 15 values).

Comment: *'I get the error message'* doesn't tell me anything that I can help you with.

Comment: sorry, I forgot to copy paste. This is the error message: 
Error parsing the formula

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice you used semi-colons. Change all commas to semi-colons. (as above)